# Different methods for handling nominal variables in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

So I am fairly new to Python and I'm trying to use the `DecisionTreeClassifier()` function from the `sklearn` package. The issue is, that I have (majority of) nominal variables, which `DecisionTreeClassifier()` cannot handle. In `R` (which I know well), this is solved easily by setting the variables to factors (`as.factor()`) and the regression function creates dummy variables automatically and removes one dummy referential variable. To do this, I used `pandas.get_dummies()` function, which does not remove the 'reference' level of the factor variable.

Does this cause any issues in the `DecisionTreeClassifier()` function? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `drop_first` argument to `True`.

```
    pandas.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True)    # df is your DataFrame
```

This creates `k-1` dummy variables instead of `k`.

Depending on the data, your decision tree classifier will probably still run with `k` dummy variables, but in general it is better to have `k-1` to avoid multicollinear variables. This is known as the [dummy variable trap](https://medium.com/@saurav9786/dummy-variable-trap-c6d4a387f10a).